# Apify Page Function modification

Tags: web-scraping, apify

Previously the page function below

```
FX: $('span[class="enhanced-table-cell-api"]').text()
```

has worked OK for a long time on an apify/web-scraper actor on https://www.asb.co.nz/foreign-exchange/foreign-exchange-rates.html

Currently (I have now way of obtaining the previous version prior to September 8) the following html/DOM inspector extract is:

```
<span class="enhanced-table-cell-api" data-api="">
  <div class="api-data-params" 
    data-api="forex" 
    data-api-attrs=
"currencycode~USD$description~$isFeatured~ $smallestNote~"
    data-default="" 
    data-prefix="" 
    data-suffix="" data-subtext=""
    data-displayfield="buysPayments" 
    data-api-url="https://api.asb.co.nz/public/v1/exchange rates"
    data-api-key="17xx93b1538ae6564c3fa170f899b645c605" 
    data-api-keyfields="" 
    data-api-mwport="">
</div>0.6771
</span>
```

I am trying to extract the '0.6671' string, and 'USD' from the first column, along with 80 or so other elements of a similar class on the page.
There must have been a change to the website as the output is now only a number of blank rows. I am looking for suggestions as to how to modify the page function to extract the values again.

Thanks for your help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use this:

```js
const values = $('span.enhanced-table-cell-api').map((index, el) => {
  const $el = $(el);

  return {
     FX: $el.text().trim(),
     currency: $el
       .find('[data-api-attrs]')
       .first()
       .attr('data-api-attrs')
       .split(/(currencyCode~|\$)/g, 3)
       .filter(s => s)[1]
  }
}).toArray();

/* 
 values now contain an array of { FX, currency } values like:
*/
const values = [
  {
    "FX": "0.9568",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9376",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9332",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9003",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5511",
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5344",
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5308",
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5109",
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5978",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5804",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5776",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5513",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "75.1556",
    "currency": "JPY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "72.7472",
    "currency": "JPY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "72.2514",
    "currency": "JPY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "69.3433",
    "currency": "JPY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.7049",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6849",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6802",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6543",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9568",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9376",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9332",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9003",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5511",
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5344",
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5308",
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5109",
    "currency": "GBP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9346",
    "currency": "CAD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9003",
    "currency": "CAD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.8968",
    "currency": "CAD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.8620",
    "currency": "CAD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "72.5986",
    "currency": "XPF"
  },
  {
    "FX": "69.4658",
    "currency": "XPF"
  },
  {
    "FX": "65.2153",
    "currency": "XPF"
  },
  {
    "FX": "5.1225",
    "currency": "CNY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "4.2675",
    "currency": "CNY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "4.4771",
    "currency": "DKK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "4.2799",
    "currency": "DKK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "4.0914",
    "currency": "DKK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5978",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5804",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5776",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5513",
    "currency": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.5422",
    "currency": "FJD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.4569",
    "currency": "FJD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.3595",
    "currency": "FJD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "5.5051",
    "currency": "HKD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "5.2880",
    "currency": "HKD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "5.2724",
    "currency": "HKD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "5.0683",
    "currency": "HKD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "47.5891",
    "currency": "INR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "75.1556",
    "currency": "JPY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "72.7472",
    "currency": "JPY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "72.2514",
    "currency": "JPY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "69.3433",
    "currency": "JPY"
  },
  {
    "FX": "6.4380",
    "currency": "NOK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "6.1602",
    "currency": "NOK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "5.8979",
    "currency": "NOK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "31.4086",
    "currency": "PHP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.9609",
    "currency": "WST"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.8693",
    "currency": "WST"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.6274",
    "currency": "WST"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9724",
    "currency": "SGD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9359",
    "currency": "SGD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.9313",
    "currency": "SGD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.8932",
    "currency": "SGD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "11.9199",
    "currency": "ZAR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "11.4809",
    "currency": "ZAR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "10.9864",
    "currency": "ZAR"
  },
  {
    "FX": "6.3117",
    "currency": "SEK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "5.9611",
    "currency": "SEK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "5.7011",
    "currency": "SEK"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6439",
    "currency": "CHF"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6203",
    "currency": "CHF"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6190",
    "currency": "CHF"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.5935",
    "currency": "CHF"
  },
  {
    "FX": "22.6152",
    "currency": "THB"
  },
  {
    "FX": "21.3390",
    "currency": "THB"
  },
  {
    "FX": "20.3135",
    "currency": "THB"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.7419",
    "currency": "TOP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.6212",
    "currency": "TOP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "1.4157",
    "currency": "TOP"
  },
  {
    "FX": "2.8737",
    "currency": "AED"
  },
  {
    "FX": "2.3155",
    "currency": "AED"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.7049",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6849",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6802",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "FX": "0.6543",
    "currency": "USD"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much $pocesar for taking the time to help me out.  Using your code, I am getting the following errors from Apify: "TypeError: $ is not a function" ... "at Object.pageFunction (<anonymous>:7:16). Sorry but I am not that good at JavaScript to figure out the cause of the error.

Comment: Hello @pocesar I fixed the error as I realised that i had commented out:  const request = context.request;
 const $ = context.jQuery; above your code. No errors now, but no output either.

Comment: @KimPrisk you need to return the `values` variable inside your Page Function ;)

Comment: Thanks, nearly there. I thought the return function in the code was the required return. Have added now and getting 89 rows back. However the FX column is empty, but the currency column is populated correctly.

Comment: I think the cause of the FX value being empty may be similar to my original issue in that the value was no longer being found by .text(). Somehow the numerical value eg .6971 that appears after /div is not in the <span> data set. Then on the other hand you seem to be capturing it ok as your result set shows it.

Comment: @KimPrisk unless you're using cheerio scraper instead of webscraper, you should be seeing the values, since they are populated using Javascript on the page

Comment: I have found out the cause of the problem in both my original page function and yours.  It is the build of the actor. Changing back to 0.1.40 from 0.1.41 fixed it. I will let Apify know.  Thanks again for your help.